# DropdownButtonFormField is not resetting first time

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I want to reset DropdownButtonFormField. I mange to reset it by setting it's value null and using globalkey as following code.

Here, problem is that i need to **click twice** to reset it.

Note: I know using DropdownButton, we can reset more easily but my question is why DropdownButtonFormField is not resetting when i click first time.

**After Update:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String abc;
  FocusNode _node = FocusNode();
  GlobalKey<FormState> _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Form(
            key: _key,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Focus(
                  focusNode: _node,
                  onFocusChange: (bool focus) {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: Listener(
                    onPointerDown: (_) {
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_node);
                    },
                    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                      hint: Text('select value'),
                      value: abc,
                      items: <String>['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].map((String value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: Text(value),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (String newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          abc = newValue;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text("value is $abc"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                abc = null;
                _key.currentState.reset();
              });
            },
            tooltip: 'Reset',
            child: Icon(Icons.clear),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `Future(() => _key.currentState.reset());` but i think its a bug

Comment: i tried that, but did not work. i also tried by putting 1 second delay between setting abc value null and reset. yes this could be bug.

Comment: it this is working in dartpad but in device(emulator ) not working.

Comment: Flutter 1.18.0-9.0.pre.38 • channel master

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, i think it is bug in latest version of master channel. @pskink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to make manual Focus
you need to give the global key to form as well

```
FocusNode _node = FocusNode();
...


  Focus(
                focusNode: _node,
                onFocusChange: (bool focus) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: Listener(
                  onPointerDown: (_) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_node);
                  },
                  child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                    iconSize: 50,
                    onChanged: (s) {
                      setState(() {
                        abc = s;
                      });
                    },
                    hint: Text(
                      'Select Text',
                    ),
                    items: [
                      DropdownMenuItem(value: '1', child: Text('A')),
                      DropdownMenuItem(value: '2', child: Text('B')),
                      DropdownMenuItem(value: '3', child: Text('C')),
                      DropdownMenuItem(value: '4', child: Text('D')),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

...
 FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              print("hello");
              abc = null;
              _key.currentState.reset();
            });
            // _flyIronMan();
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. i tried but did not workout, can you add full minimal code ?

Comment: This is still not working. i updated my current code in question can you check it ?

Comment: don't give the value of ```DropdownButtonFormField``` after your code is working as you want

Comment: i have to add future then your code is working in dartpad but in emulator it is still not working.

Comment: I think you don't need Future here just remove value property in DropdownButtonFormField widget

Comment: did you try in device ? this is somehow not working in emulator. i also think same as you.

Comment: I think this is bug in latest version of flutter can you check to latest version and check? Thank you for you response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212671/discussion-between-abhishek-ghaskata-and-viren-v-varasadiya).